# How to completely disable Subpixel rendering in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, accessibility, cleartype

I am - unfortunately - one of the persons, for whom subpixel rendering is a visual burden instead of a help. So I am trying to disable it completely in Windows 8.1, but it still pops up a lot of places.

I have disabled ClearType in the Display control panel, which is respected by some applications. But Windows still use subpixel rendering in e.g. the control panel and other places.

Is there any way to disable it for all text-rendering?

Comment: @Techie007 that may be so, but the answer (points 2 & 3) below definitely hasn't been posted before.

Answer (score 0):

There is *font smoothing* in addition the *ClearType*. Briefly, quoting from [Disable ClearType everywhere](http://ucla.jamesyxu.com/?p=22):

1. Disable ClearType by opening “Control Panel->Fonts->Adjust ClearType text” and unchecking “Turn on ClearType”.
2. Disable font smoothing by unchecking “Smooth edges of screen fonts” in “Control Panel->System->Advanced system settings -> Performance Settings->Visual Effects.
3. Change window elements fonts. To do this, open “Control Panel->Personalize->Window Color->Advanced appearance settings” and change all fonts from Segoe UI 9 to any other font.

See the reference above and [Disable all font smoothing in Windows 7 (ie: including taskbar, menus, control panel, etc...)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/disable-all-font-smoothing-in-windows-7-ie/f180e803-3317-4433-8fd2-63aadaecc2d2) for more complete directions, still applicable to Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Pippik I had already tried 1 & 2 (also through regedit), but 3) is new to me - will try it tomorrow when I'm back at the computer in question. Thanks

Comment: @Pippik 3) is unfortunately not available in Windows 8.1. Sometimes I simply don't understand what goes on inside the head of those Windows development teams...

Comment: A developers motto: "If it ain't broke, it don't have enough features." (adapted from Dilbert, http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Scott_Adams)